# insert and update multiple documents mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, mongoose

I know there's a lot of threads about this subject - but i still didn't find anything that matches my situation.
There is a big database with companies and products schema's.
Each company uploads their products, (product has "company" field with the mongo id of the company)
My operation goes like this - 
Company uploads array of products.
Each product has his own productId.
I need to insert all the products in to the DB but -

1. If i find product with the same productId - update it - if not - insert a new product.
2. Change some fields (change product "status" to "deleted") to all of the products that belongs to that company in the DB, that didn't match any of the product id's (from the array of products the user uploaded).

I'm searching for a better solution than the one i'm using, my process goes like this -

1. fetching all the company's products.
2. looping through all of the products - and updating a field (status = "deleted") building a mapping object for each product, so i can identify it and check if it exists in the uploaded array.
3. looping through the company's array (with async library), checking if product exists (in the mapping array), if exists - updating it, if not - create a new product.

It feels very sloppy and i'm sure there is a better way to do it.

the thing i tried to use is -

```
      await Product.updateMany({ productStatus: { $ne: 'manual'} , company: {$eq: company._id}}, { $set: {status: 'deleted' }});
```

and then

```
    Product.bulkWrite(
    productsArray.map((row) => 
      ({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { productId: row.productId, company: row.company },
          update: row,
          upsert: true
        }
      })
    )
  )
```

It was super slow (my method was faster even thought it's more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

> If i find product with the same productId - update it - if not - insert a new product.

You can use [upserts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/), which is a find-and-modify operation with `upsert: true` set. Pass the whole product document.

> Change some fields (change product "status" to "deleted") to all of the products that belongs to that company in the DB, that didn't match any of the product id's (from the array of products the user uploaded).

You can use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) to update the status on all products whose ids are not in the list of currently available products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you show me some example? i'm not sure i understood how to apply it in my code

Comment: Both of the pages referenced have examples.